# Transform entire column as a corpus

Tags: python, dataframe, corpus

df have two columns containing text. I want to transform them to corpus separately.

df

```
id | Description 1                   |Description 2       |
-----------------------------------------------------------
1  |that book is good                | better than book2  |
2  |book 2 is not better than 1      | not good           |
.  |            .                    |      .             |
.  |            .                    |      .             |
.  |            .                    |      .             |
```

Consider Description 1  is the document and  Description 2 is the query.

Expected Output

```
Corpus 1: that book is good book 2 is not better than 1..................
Corpus 2: better than book2 not good.....................
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected result?

Comment: Corpus 1: that book is good book 2 is not better than 1..................
Corpus 2: better than book2 not good.....................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the every rows that avaliable in the column using join function and then append it.Output is in list format

```
corpus = []
for i  in range(len(df.columns)):
    corpus.append(' '.join(df.iloc[j,i] for j in range(len(df.iloc[:,i]))))
```

Comment: I tried ```corpus = []
for i  in range(len(df_processed2.columns)):
    corpus.append(' '.join(df_processed2['Input_Description'].iloc[j,i] for j in range(len(df_processed2.iloc[:,i]))))``` But it resulted in an error, ```IndexingError: Too many indexers```

Comment: yeah in append lie you are giving more index so what it is displaying error

Comment: instead of this -> corpus.append(' '.join(df_processed2['Input_Description'].iloc[j,i] for j in range(len(df_processed2.iloc[:,i]))))    change to  corpus.append(' '.join(df_processed2.iloc[j,i] for j in range(len(df_processed2.iloc[:,i]))))

Comment: if you feel the answer is right Accept it

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.int64 found

Comment: yeah you need to feed object columns but your 1st column is int that is id->df.drop('id',axis =1).remove the id column if it is not neccessary or otherwise while looping skip that

Comment: Then all other two columns will result as a single corpus right? I want them as different corpus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230843/discussion-between-yid-and-amzzz).

Comment: And I tried ```col1=Description 1    corpus = []
for i  in range(len(col1.columns)):
    corpus.append(' '.join(col.iloc[j,i] for j in range(len(col.iloc[:,i]))))     ```        But it also resulted in error. AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'.

Comment: yeah because you are selecting only one column that will automaically change to series

Comment: corpus = []
df.drop('id',axis = 1,inplace = True)
for i  in range(len(df.columns)):
    corpus.append(' '.join(df.iloc[j,i] for j in range(len(df.iloc[:,i]))))

Comment: I want to make them different corpus

Comment: run the above code it will give the output what you are expecting

Comment: Ok! Now I can fetch them as corpus[0] and corpus[1] right?